# Insert "X" between identical consecutive letters in a string

Tags: python

Given a string, how can I break it up such that there are no consecutive identical letters, at n, n+1, where n is even.

Meaning, how can i get "abba" to remain "abba", but take "abbb" into "abbXb".

Thanks

Comment: Is n starting at 0? Also what have you tried?

Comment: what result do you expect from "aaaaaa" ?

Answer (score 1):

Because everyone loves one-liners:

```
strings = ['ab', 'abba', 'abbb', 'abbba', 'abbababababbbaaaa', 'abcacbbbddbabbdd']

for s in strings:
    r = ''.join('X' + v if (k and k % 2 and v == s[k - 1]) else v for (k,v) in enumerate(s))
    print s, '->', r
```

The code reads like this: look at every character in the string. If it's not the first and if it's index is even and it is the same as the character before, prepend an `'X'` to the character.

Output:

```
ab -> ab
abba -> abba
abbb -> abbXb
abbba -> abbXba
abbababababbbaaaa -> abbababababXbbaaXaa
abcacbbbddbabbdd -> abcacbbXbdXdbabXbdXd
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your own homework, Kevin.

```
def foo(text, separator):
    if len(text) < 2:
        return text

    result = ""
    for i in range(1, len(text), 2):
        if text[i] == text[i - 1]:
            result += text[i - 1] + separator + text[i]
        else:
            result += text[i-1:i+1]

    if len(text) % 2 != 0:
        result += text[-1]

    return result

print(foo("ab", "X"))
print(foo("abba", "X"))
print(foo("abbba", "X"))
print(foo("abbababababbbaaaa", "Z"))
```

Output:

```
>> ab
>> abba
>> abbXba
>> abbababababZbbaaZaa
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import islice, groupby
import math
def solve(strs, n):
    for k, g in groupby(strs):
        lis = list(g)
        it = iter(lis)
        yield 'X'.join(''.join(islice(it, n)) for _ in xrange(int(math.ceil(len(lis)/float(n)))))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> ''.join(solve("abba", 2))
'abba'
>>> ''.join(solve("abbb", 2))
'abbXb'
>>> ''.join(list(solve('abbbbyyyyy', 2)))
'abbXbbyyXyyXy'
>>> ''.join(solve('abbbbyyyyy', 4))
'abbbbyyyyXy'
```

Answer (score 0):

May it be good?

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def X(s):
    s_odd = s[::2]
    s_even = s[1::2]
    output = ''
    for o, e in izip_longest(s_odd, s_even):
        output += o or ''
        if o == e:
            output += 'X'
        output += e or ''
    return output

strings = ['ab', 'abba', 'abbb', 'abbba', 'abbababababbbaaaa', 'abcacbbbddbabbdd']
for s in strings:
    print X(s)
```

result:

```
ab
abba
abbXb
abbXba
abbababababXbbaaXaa
abcacbbXbdXdbabXbdXd
```

**EDIT**

A simpler version:

```
def X(s):
    output = ''
    for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
        o = s[i]
        e = s[i+1] if i < len(s) - 1 else ''
        output += o
        if o == e:
            output += 'X'
        output += e
    return output

strings = ['ab', 'abba', 'abbb', 'abbba', 'abbababababbbaaaa', 'abcacbbbddbabbdd']
for s in strings:
    print X(s)
```